# docker build throws java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect UnknownHostException with jenkins dind slave + kubernetes plugin

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, dns, amazon-eks, docker-in-docker

So Jenkins is installed inside the cluster with this [official helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/jenkins). And this is my installed plugins as per helm release values:

```
  installPlugins:
  - kubernetes:1.18.1
  - workflow-job:2.33
  - workflow-aggregator:2.6
  - credentials-binding:1.19
  - git:3.11.0
  - blueocean:1.19.0
```

my Jenkinsfile relies on the following pod template to spin up slaves:

```
kind: Pod
spec:
  # dnsConfig:
  #   options:
  #     - name: ndots
  #       value: "1"
  containers:
  - name: dind
    image: docker:19-dind
    command:
    - cat
    tty: true
    volumeMounts:
    - name: dockersock
      readOnly: true
      mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: 500m
        memory: 512Mi
  volumes:
  - name: dockersock
    hostPath: 
      path: /var/run/docker.sock
```

Slaves (pod /dind container) starts nicely as expected whenever there is new Build.

However, it broke at the step of "docker build" in ( Jenkinsfile pipeline
 `docker build -t ...` ) and it breaks there :

```
Step 16/24 : RUN      ../gradlew clean bootJar

 ---> Running in f14b6418b3dd

Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.5-all.zip


Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: services.gradle.org

    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:220)

    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)

    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591)

    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:285)

    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)

    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:182)

    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474)

    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:569)

    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:265)

    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:372)

    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)

    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1187)

    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1081)

    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)

    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1587)

    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1515)

    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)

    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:67)

    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:52)

    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:62)

    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)

    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)

    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)

    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)

    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:63)

The command '/bin/sh -c ../gradlew clean bootJar' returned a non-zero code:
```

At the first galance, I thought it's DNS resolution issue with the Slave container (`docker:19-dind`) since it is alpine.
That's why I debug its `/etc/resolv.conf` by adding `sh "cat /etc/resolv.conf"` in the Jenkinsfile.

I got :

```
nameserver 172.20.0.10
search cicd.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local ap-southeast-1.compute.internal
options ndots:5
```

I removed the last line `options ndots:5` as per recommendation of many thread on the internet.

But it does not fix the issue.

I thought again and again and I realized that the container responsible for this error is not the Slave (docker:19-dind), instead, it is the intermediate containers that are opened to satisfy `docker build`.

As consequence,  I added `RUN cat /etc/resolv.conf` as another layer in the Dockerfile (which starts by `FROM gradle:5.5-jdk11`).

Now, the `resolv.conf` is different :

```
Step 15/24 : RUN cat /etc/resolv.conf

 ---> Running in 91377c9dd519

; generated by /usr/sbin/dhclient-script

search ap-southeast-1.compute.internal

options timeout:2 attempts:5

nameserver 10.0.0.2

Removing intermediate container 91377c9dd519

 ---> abf33839df9a

Step 16/24 : RUN      ../gradlew clean bootJar

 ---> Running in f14b6418b3dd

Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.5-all.zip

Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: services.gradle.org
```

Basically, it is a different nameserver `10.0.0.2` than the nameserver of the slave container `172.20.0.10`. There is NO `ndots:5` in resolv.conf this intermediate container.

I was confused after all these debugging steps and a lot of attempts.

### Architecture

```
Jenkins Server (Container )
     ||
(spin up slaves)
     ||__ SlaveA (Container, image: docker:19-dind)
             ||
       ( run "docker build" )
             ||
             ||_ intermediate (container, image: gradle:5.5-jdk11 )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `--network=host` to `docker build` or `docker run`.

```
 docker build --network=host foo/bar:latest .
```

Found the answer [here](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami/issues/183#issuecomment-463687956)